# Chromebook won’t turn on

Tags: chromebook

I have a hp Chromebook and it basically won’t turn on, like at all.
When I plug in the charger, the light that usually turns on to show that it’s charging, isn’t there. I know my charger isn’t broken because I use it to charge my switch, but I just don’t know what to do. I tried a hard reset already and it wouldn’t turn on.

Comment: You need a repair-shop, but I'm not sure it's worth it or at all possible.

Comment: If it is under warranty I would return it. Model number would help. Battery replacement?

Comment: If possible - replace the battery but apart from that, there isnt much you can do.

Comment: You've done a pretty good job of troubleshooting this but there are a couple of things you can still try explained here under "Is The Chromebook Charging?"  https://www.schooledintech.com/7-easy-chromebook-troubleshooting-tips/

I'd start trying to detect a power connector problem by wiggling the connector around in the socket.